# ASP.NET Core - Add Controller - API Controller with actions, using Entity Framework - Throws error and Downgrades NuGet EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

In a ASP.NET Core project I run `Add Controller` - `API Controller with actions, using Entity Framework` from Visual Studio 2019.

[image]

I then get the following error:

> Error
>
> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Could not
> load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer,
> Version=5.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
> The system cannot find the file specified.'

[image]

If I take a look at Git I can see that Visual Studio has automatically downgraded `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` to `5.0.9`.

[image]

If I run the exact same code again it will work.

I'm running the latest `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.3` and all the latest NuGet packages. I can only update `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` that Visual Studio automatically downgraded.

[image]

Is this a bug in Visual Studio or something else?

Comment: Could be related to [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1555)?

Comment: @RichardDeeming That seems to be Identity related but comments mention downgrade as well. This is exactly the same however:
https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1649

Comment: I get it on a regular basis. I clear the cache, and sometimes it helps. Sometimes not. Then I give up and use the option without EF and add EF stuff manually. Then a few weeks later it suddenly starts working. So, I *do* believe that it is some bug in VS

Comment: @Felix Same here but it is a bit annoying though...

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible if you have two dependencies (project, package) and each of them depends on EF but from different versions. Also, dependence can be transitive.

For the old `.csproj` this could be fixed by the child XML element. I am not sure if there is an alternative for the new .csproj

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0"/>
```

Also, this issue is fixed in the alternative for NuGet
https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/

Comment: I'm looking at NuGets for the solution and every project has the same version. No difference for any packages.

Answer (score 0):

try these

1. update all of your NuGet package
2. clean solution
3. rebuild

Comment: Tried, does not work